# AVRO class cast exception

Tags: java, avro

Hi so in my spring listener consumer i keep getting the following error thrown, when i attempt to get the value..

```
  public void listen(ConsumerRecord<String, Car> consumerRecord) {
    Car value = consumerRecord.value();
    int i= 0;
}
```

---

```
  java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to class com.test.avro.Car (org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record and com.test.avro.Car are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Comment: Need more details. How is Car class created?

Comment: @OneCricketeer it is created via avro plugin, its from avro schema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to add the following to the configuration

```
props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, "true");
```